# Move uploaded file failing

Tags: php

So i have just moved everything from my localhost to a new online server to get it running. Obviously there are bound to be a few problems but this one i cannot sort out. I cannot upload any files but I could on localhost. I spoke to one of the server companies support team and we have checked all php.ini, htaccess etc and everything is fine. The upload max and post max is way higher than it needs to be. The uploads folder has all the correct permisions. Moving the uploaded file is failing completely and I do not know why.

Here is the image upload script (well the importan part):

```
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg1']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
{

    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET image1='../imageuploads/$actual_image_name' WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$pass' AND artist='Y'");

    echo "<p1><img src='../imageuploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='imageright1'></p1>";

}else
    echo "<p1>failed</p1>";
```

The error message I get is this:

> PHP Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(../imageuploads/13403748125_277695398952342_104081122980438_707146_2014948057_n.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/vhosts/lvps217-199-163-188.vps.webfusion.co.uk/httpdocs/imageupload/ajaximage1.php
>   on line 39, referer: http:/217.199.163.188/artistupdate.html

There is probably something very simple that I havent done but i cannot figure out for the life of me what it is. The image upload script is fairly simple but the audio upload script is a bit more complex so haven't included it. They both get the same error from the same place anyhow.;

Comment: Please var_dump($_FILES, $_POST) and show us the relevant information by editing your post

Comment: Could this be a typo issue? I notice in your error, one directory is called 'imageuploads' and the other is 'imageupload'.

Comment: No thats not it. I dont know why i chose those names but imageupload is where the scripts are and imageuploads is the destination folder for all image uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update query is using `../imageuploads`, yet your generated path for the move command is simply `imageuploads`, so you're probably not pointing the move command at the right directory.

Comment: Sorry copy n pasted the wrong error i have moved a few folder about so this is not it

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked folder permissions?

Comment: Yes all permission are fine. The uploads folder has all the correct permisions for uploading